# set global encoding in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, encoding, zend-validate

My bootstrap sets encoding for all views:

```
protected function _initView () {
    $view = new Zend_View();
    // snip...
    $view->setEncoding('utf-8');
    // snip...
    return $view;
}
```

However, this does not set encoding for my form validators. The `StringLength` uses its default encoding (I'm not sure which that is) and it counts diacritics as two characters.

I know I can set the `'encoding' => 'utf-8'` option when creating the validator, but it's kind of pesky to update all validators across my entire (huge) application. Is there a way to set the encoding for all validators at the same time?

Comment: I wonder if setting default_charset to utf-8 in your php.ini would help?

Comment: Shared hosting. Already tried it and it doesn't seem to work :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ZF 1.1x the `StringLength` validator uses `iconv_strlen`:

```
int iconv_strlen(string $str [, string $charset = ini_set("iconv.internal_encoding")])
```

So one thing to try is to call `ini_set` (or `iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', $encoding);`).

Answer (score 2):

You normally shouldn't have a problem with that if you've sent the Content-Type very early + defined it in the HTML-Document.

In PHP you can send the Encoding at the Entry-Point (which is in Zend Framework the "index.php"-File):

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

In your HTML-Layout you should place the META-Tag within your HEAD-Tag:

```
<!-- do this only in: HTML5 -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!-- do this only in: HTML4 -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And, of course, save every Source-File (HTML+PHP-Files) within the Project in UTF-8 (without BOM)

Comment: You could add the possibility to add this already to the .htaccess `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`.

Comment: Nope. My document is XHTML with UTF-8 set already. This has no influence whatsoever on the encoding the validator uses.

Answer (score 1):

May be a bit late, but this would be the full answer:

```
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'utf-8');
```